# dynamic variable content is not passing correctly to adf notebook activity from databricks

Tags: python, azure, pyspark, azure-data-factory, databricks

I have recently encountered a problem when passing the HTML string from Databricks to adf using notebook activity.
Some of the dynamic content generated in the for loop is missing in the final variable string in the adf notebook activity output.

table_string = """

```
table_string = """
<html>
<table>
 <tr><th>ColumnName</th></tr>
"""

for row in df.collect():
 value = str(row["ColumnName"])
 table_string += "<tr><td>"+str(value)+"</tr></td>"

table_string += """
</table>
</html>
"""

print(table_string)
dbutils.notebook.exit(table_string)

when I run the above code in the Databricks notebook I get the correct output as below.
<html>
<table>
 <tr><th>ColumnName</th></tr>
 <tr><td>valueName</td></tr>
</table>
</html>

but when the notebook.exit is used to send the content to adf notebook activity output. it is only sending the content as below
<html>
<table>
 <tr><th>ColumnName</th></tr>
</table>
</html>

** <tr><td>valueName</td></tr>** is missing in the adf notebook output.
```

"""

Comment: Looks like df is empty when you run it from ADF, you can check it by adding df.count(). Go to Databricks and under workflows check the run history of this notebook.

Comment: Df is not empty . The html string is being generated properly when the code is running from databricks .. it is only happening when running it from adf

Comment: I meant it's empty when running from ADF. perhaps because of different parameters?

Answer (score 0):

> dynamic variable content is not passing correctly to adf notebook activity from databricks

When you want to get the dynamic variable content is not passing correctly to adf notebook activity

You need to use the `columnname = dbutils.widgets.get("columnname")`  this command to get the dynamic variable to pass the column name.

Also make sure you have values in dataframe when you are running the databricks notebook from ADF.

Make sure you have dataframe present in the same cell where you are creating this HTML.

```py
columnname = dbutils.widgets.get("columnname")

from pyspark.sql import Row
# Define the schema for the DataFrame
data = [Row(name="Alice", age=25),Row(name="Bob", age=30),Row(name="Charlie", age=22)]
schema = ["name", "age"]
# Create a DataFrame using the SparkSession and the Row data
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=schema)
# Show the DataFrame
df.show()
table_string = f"""<html>
<table>
    <tr><th>{columnname}</th></tr>
"""
for row in df.collect():
    value = str(row[columnname])
    table_string +=  "<tr><td>"+str(value)+"</tr></td>"
table_string +=  """
</table>
</html>
"""
print(table_string)
dbutils.notebook.exit(table_string)
```

**Here you can see the Notebook Executed Successfully:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]